# Git keep latest commit but delete the one before

Tags: git, gerrit, git-commit

I'm trying to push the newest Git-Commit to gerrit.
But somehow I get an error message saying that I can't push, because two commits have the same Change-ID.

In the image below you can see the current situation.

1. The third commit (from the top) is already pushed to gerrit.
2. The third and the second commit somehow have the same Change-ID.
3. I want to push the first commit to gerrit.

[image]
.

So my idea to fix this problem would be to delete the second commit.
Is this possible?

Comment: What do you mean by "same change-id"? Are you talking about the hash of the commit? the 40-character hexadecimal string, or something else?

Comment: Every git-commit has a commit-id (40-character hexadecimal string).
What I'm talking about is the change-id (also a 40-character hexadecimal string) . The change-id is added at the end of a commit message and it's use by gerrit to organize the different commits I think.

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen: "change ID" is a Gerrit-ism. Not having used Gerrit myself I can't tell you what generates it, but it's outside Git proper.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose the commit hashes of the three commits from top to bottom are A, B and C.

Make sure `git status` tells it's clean. If not, run `git stash` first.

If you really don't want B any more,

```
git reset C --hard
git cherry-pick A
```

If you still want B,

```
git reset B --hard
git commit --amend
# Edit the commit message and delete the change-id line, save and exit.
# The commit-msg hook will generate a new changeid.
git cherry-pick A
```

And then push again.

Comment: Perfect, thats what I was searching for.

One more question:
Suppose I do the first procedure, B won't be there anymore, right?
What will happen with the changes from B? Will they also be removed, or will they be attached to A or C?

Comment: @npkllr B and its changes are not in the current branch any more, although they are still in the local repository.

Comment: If B isn't accessible by any ref they would be accessible until cleared by git's GC. Until that time you could use B hash as any other, so `git show B`, `git checkout B`, etc. would work. When B gets deleted you'll see `fatal: bad object B` error message.

Comment: `reset` followed by `cherry-pick` works, but it's probably easier to use `rebase -i`

Comment: @WilliamPursell Agree. But I always find it more difficult to explain how to use `git rebase -i`.